# Add embedded plugin jar file to a project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to add some jar libraries to a project with my plugin by modifying classpath entry. But i can't find a way to do that. I tried to nested jar lib inside the lib folder of my plugin but i can't access them when the plugin is packaged as Jar and deploy on an eclipse IDE.
Any Solution?
What is the right way to do this?

This is the code that add lib to the target project :

```
private void addLocalLibrary(IProject parent, String name, boolean source, boolean javadoc)
    throws CoreException, URISyntaxException, IOException {
IClasspathEntry[] oldEntries = this.javaProject.getRawClasspath();
// +1 for our src/main/java entry
IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[oldEntries.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(oldEntries, 0, newEntries, 0, oldEntries.length);

String pluginDir = new File(Activator.getPluginDir()).getAbsolutePath().replace("file:", "");
IPackageFragmentRoot lib = this.javaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot(pluginDir + "/" + name);
IPackageFragmentRoot src = null;
if (source) {
    src = this.javaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot((pluginDir + "/" + name).replace(".jar", "-sources.jar"));
}
IClasspathAttribute atts[] = null;
if (javadoc) {
    IPackageFragmentRoot doc = this.javaProject
        .getPackageFragmentRoot((pluginDir + "/" + name).replace(".jar", "-javadoc.jar"));
    atts = new IClasspathAttribute[] {
        JavaCore.newClasspathAttribute("javadoc_location", doc.getPath().toString()), };
}
IPath srcPath = src == null ? null : src.getPath();
newEntries[oldEntries.length] = JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(lib.getPath(), srcPath, null, null, atts, true);
this.javaProject.setRawClasspath(newEntries, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a plugin from the existing library jar and add it to the dependencies of the plugin where you want to use the library code.

To do so, use the *Plug-in from existing JAR archives wizard*, which is available under **File > New > Project... > Plug-in Development > Plug-in from existing JAR archive**.

This way you can wrap existing jars in a plugin project. You can also use this plugin as the base for your own code. If you want to package as a single jar, make sure to unzip the library jar into the plugin.

Comment: I know this possibility but how can i use this Library Plugin to include it in the target Project?

Comment: @Scandinave Why don't you just use it as a plugin dependency?

Comment: Yes i just see , i can do that. Thinks, i will work to this.